# Setting up SSH key for Jenkins on Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh

I have setup a SSH key on my Windows 10 computer which works fine without asking for a password when I run the normal SSH connect command:

```
ssh username@123.456.789.01
```

I need to use the same command as part of a build step in Jenkins which is running on Docker. I copied the `id_rsa` files to `/jenkins/.ssh` and the file is readable to Docker/Jenkins.

The problem is I keep getting an error of:

```
Permissions 0755 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
Permission denied, please try again.
```

If I run the `sh whoami` it returns `root` as the username. I have checked the security settings on the `id_rsa` file and set it to only username `root` having permissions (no other user has permissions). This didn't solve it.

I have tried changing the username on the file to several different ones including `jenkins`, `Administrator`, `MyAccountName` etc but it does not work. The same error comes back saying `Permissions 0755 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.`.

All the solutions I have read so far talk about `chmod 700` on the file but I am on Windows 10 and don't have that command.

How do I set the permissions on the file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have access to the Linux shell of the system that Jenkins is running on, you can try to run the `chmod 600 <path to key file>` as a part of the build step in a dummy job. Also, make sure that the folder in which the key is has proper permission rights.

After that, you can do `ssh -i <path to key file> username@123.456.789.01`

Comment: well that worked! thank you arun really appreciate it